# Error in unzip(file, exdir = tmp) : 'exdir' does not exist (Windows 10 R Installation)

Tags: r

I receive the error message "Error in unzip(file, exdir = tmp) : 'exdir' does not exist" when I try to run a package command from a Windows 10 R installation.

Unfortunately I do not have the capability to run the unzip as an individual command since a package runs this as one of their compiled commands.

- the tmp directory is created to C:\
- I changed my permissions to full-control for the C:\tmp folder

From the other posts many were able to work around this error by removing the "/" at the end of the path.  Unfortunately because this is another packages script I'm not able to directly control the path were the unzip is performed.

Comment: can you provide more information, like your used package command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that a trailing slash can cause this problem. However, if you have no control over how `unzip` is called, then I believe your only "certain" way to fix this is to get support from the package author.

Having said that, give this a try. It does not work 100%, but it might get you far-enough until the proper fix is available. We're going to overwrite the `unzip` function (in *this* R session) with one that better accommodates a trailing slash.

First, all we're going to do is prepend

```
exdir <- gsub("[\\/]$", "", exdir)
C_unzip <- utils:::C_unzip
```

to the code. The first line just removes a trailing slash (backward or forward) from the `exdir` variable. The second line is a workaround for namespace search. (It's necessary, press the <kbd>I Believe</kbd> button.)

In my testing, this is sufficient to preclude the error (`'exdir' does not exist`) with trailing slashes. So how do we overwrite the function contents?

1. Call `fixInNamespace("unzip", "utils")`, insert the above lines as the first two lines of code in the function (before `if (identical(unzip, "internal"))`), then save.
2. Write your own version of the function and overwrite it. Get the source of the function (by typing `unzip` on the R console) and assign it to your own function, say `unzip2`:

   ```
   unzip2 <- function (zipfile, files = NULL, list = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, 
                       junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", unzip = "internal", setTimes = FALSE) {
       exdir <- gsub("[\\/]$", "", exdir)  # <-- new line 1 of 2
       C_unzip <- utils:::C_unzip          # <-- new line 2 of 2
       if (identical(unzip, "internal")) {
           if (!list && !missing(exdir)) 
             dir.create(exdir, showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
           res <- .External(C_unzip, zipfile, files, exdir, list, 
                            overwrite, junkpaths, setTimes)
           ...
   ```

   (I've omitted most of the function, partially for brevity, and partially because this method is not for the faint-of-heart. If you aren't willing to get the source of the function yourself, perhaps you shouldn't be trying this method.)

   Then we need to move that to the proper namespace:

   ```
   assignInNamespace("unzip", unzip2, "utils")
   ```

With this fix:

```
unzip("somefile.zip", exdir="path/to/dir")         # succeeds, as before
unzip("somefile.zip", exdir="path/to/dir/")        # fails despite patch
utils::unzip("somefile.zip", exdir="path/to/dir/") # succeeds, because of patch
```

So this is an imperfect patch that might work depending on how the package functions are calling `unzip`. I believe the problem is due to namespace search, but I don't understand enough (obviously) to be able to preempt it at this stage. (Community help, please?) I have seen this type of solution requested/discussed in other channels, often with the caveat of *"it sometimes works, but ..."*, so perhaps this is our limit.

But really, your better fix is to talk to the package author/maintainer.